# Removing the URL and @REPLIES from a tweet

Tags: xml, twitter

```
enter code
```

for($i=0;$ientry);$i++)
{

```
//get the id from entry
$id = $xml->entry[$i]->id;

//explode the $id by ":"
$id_parts = explode(":",$id);

//the last part is the tweet id
$tweet_id = array_pop($id_parts);

//get the account link
$account_link = $xml->entry[$i]->author->uri;

//get the image link
$image_link = $xml->entry[$i]->link[1]->attributes()->href;

//get name from entry and trim the last ")"
$name = trim($xml->entry[$i]->author->name, ")");   

//explode $name by the rest "(" inside it
$name_parts = explode("(", $name);  

//get the real name of user from the last part
$real_name = trim(array_pop($name_parts));

//the rest part is the screen name
$screen_name = trim(array_pop($name_parts));

//get the published time, replace T & Z with " " and trim the last " "
$published_time = trim(str_replace(array("T","Z")," ",$xml->entry[$i]->published));

//get the status link
$status_link = $xml->entry[$i]->link[0]->attributes()->href;

//get the tweet 
$tweet = $xml->entry[$i]->content;

//remove <b> and </b> from the tweet. If you want to show bold keyword then you can comment this line
$tweet = str_replace(array("<b>", "</b>"),array("<p><big><big>",""), $tweet);

//get the source link
$source = $xml->entry[$i]->source;

//the result div that holds the information
echo '<div class="result" id="'. $tweet_id .'">
        <div class="profile_image"><a href="'. $account_link .'"><img src="'. $image_link .'"></a></div>
         <div class="status">
            <div class="content">
                 '. $tweet .'
            </div><br>

        </div>
      </div>';
```

}echo "";

in the code .$tweet variable contains the tweet text but also contains the url's that have been tweeted,#hashtags and @replies.

i want to remove them from the tweet and only thing remaining should be the text content.
How do i do that?

any help will be appreciated.
thnx ya'll

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex will do it:

```
$cleanText = preg_replace("/[#@]\\S+/", "", $tweetText);
```